# Synchronizing Spring cache based on record id

Tags: java, spring, caching, synchronization

I have two functions:
First, whenever user asks for a value based on key, i search the database and store the result in cache for faster future references. @Cacheable notation helped me in achieving this.
Second, whenever user wants to update the value, instead of directly doing the db update operation, I want to update the cache and use a scheduled task to later update the db. I used @CachePut for this.

```
@Cacheable(key="#id")
public String getDoc(String id){
    // fetch value from database
    return val;    // will store value in cache
}

@CachePut(key="#id")
public String setDoc(String id, String newVal){
    return newVal;    // will update value in cache
}
```

Now in a multi-threaded environment, if multiple users try to update the same value in cache, it might lead to race condition which i want to prevent.

**My aim is to synchronize the below mentioned flow**
Call getDoc(id) to get existing value
Perform some calculations to modify the value
Call setDoc(id, newVal) to update the value

**I want the lock to be achieved only if the users are updating the same record**, so I cannot synchronize the above flow by putting it in a synchronized block. I read about `sync=true` attribute for @Cacheable annotation, but it doesn't work with @CachePut.
Can someone please suggest an approach to achieve this?

Comment: What version of Spring do you use?

Comment: Spring boot 2.1

Comment: Have you seen this post? https://www.foreach.be/blog/spring-cache-annotations-some-tips-tricks

Comment: Yeah, it also suggests applying sync=true in Cacheable but how do I do it here? I have CachePut here. Or can you suggest some changes here only so that I can incorporate the suggested methods?

Comment: What about using `synchronized` keyword with these two methods?

Comment: Wont work because in case of Cacheable, the synchronization happens after the cache lookup has already happened

Comment: Don't use `@CachePut` instead evict the entry and the next one caling `getDoc` (which then used `sync`) will get the proper version from db.

Comment: I thought about that but the problem is that setDoc() isn't actually making the entry in db. There's a scheduled task running which would update the db from cache entries every hour or so. In that case, the new entry won't be in db so getDoc will fail.