# How does sync parameter in Cacheable annotation work?

Tags: java, spring, caching, synchronization

The `@Cacheable` annotation in Spring **runs the method at first invocation**, and then caches the result. **For future references, it does not actually run the method**, just returns the cached result.

The sync parameter says:

> Synchronize the invocation of the underlying method if several threads
>   are attempting to load a value for the same key.

So my question is when is this synchronization applied? Is it only during the first invocation, because after that the method isn't actually invoked? Why is it that `@Cacheable` was synchronized while `@CachePut` was not?

> The difference between `@Cacheable` and `@CachePut` is that `@Cacheable`
>   will skip running the method, whereas `@CachePut` will actually run the
>   method and then put its results in the cache.

It makes more sense to use sync with an annotation that actually runs the method and updates the cache i.e. `@CachePut`. Since `@Cacheable` cannot update the existing entry in cache, why do we need synchronization? What am I missing here? What is the process happening behind the scenes?

Comment: To prevent dual execution for the same key, which could overwrite the value when initializing. This is especially welcome when calling a very expensive method. The `@CachePut` will always put a value in the cache after calling the method, `syncronizing` that would only lead to additional wait time for other threads.

Comment: Even if dual execution happens, it will always bring the same value so there will never be a race condition. `@CachePut` updates the value so getting the value after 1st invocation and getting it after second invocation will have different values which might lead to race condition.

Comment: It isn't about race condition but about saving computations. The `@CachePut` won't get it, it will only put the value, which is what the annotation is mend to do, regardless of sync execution. Also even with a sync you might get a race condition as the lock would be released after method exexution if you get it after that, you don't ahve a the lock anymore and someone else migh already updated the cache value. So it isn't about preventing race conditions but about saving computations.

Comment: But you can save computation only once at the start. Once the value is in cache, the method doesn't execute so there is no computation. Why do we need `sync` then?

Comment: Read my first comment. Imagine 10 calls to the method with the same parameter(s), 1 second after each other. Assume that the method execution takes 10 seconds (heavy computatin, slow resource etc). Now only the first one will execute the method and all others will benefit from that first execution. The first one will take 10 seconds to execute, the last one only about a second because the result is already there. Without sync all would take the same amount or longer if for instance a slow constrained resource is being used.

Comment: Ohh i got it, thanks for the example. The sync in `@Cacheable` makes sense now.

Comment: Can you help me with another question about same topic? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61934910/synchronizing-spring-cache-based-on-record-id